# How does ことし配信された動画配信大手 work as an attribute here

Tags: grammar

The sentence in question:
きっかけは、ことし配信された動画配信大手ネットフリックスの番組。

For full context:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20190314/k10011847731000.html?utm_int=news_contents_tokushu_004

My attempt at translation:
"The start, it was this years program of netflix, the big videostreaming company."

The problem is that I dont really know whether I connected ことし correctly or not. The boom started this year and it was because of netflix, that much I already know. But I'm still a bit uncertain because ことし is very distant from 番組 itself, positionwise at least, although it is in the direct vicinity of the phrase modifying 番組.

Also, 配信された動画配信 confuses me。動画配信 itself already contains the distribution of information. But then 配信された is used to express that it was distributed. It feels redundant and if I translate 配信された動画配信大手ネットフリックスの番組 in isolation it doesnt make much sense to me either:
"the program of the big video streaming company netflix which distributed."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This ことし is an adverbial that modifies the phrase right after it, 配信された. Read 動画配信大手 as "a large movie streaming *company*". X大手 is a way to say "big X company." For example, Toyota is a 自動車製造大手. 動画配信大手 is in apposition to ネットフリックス.

> ことし配信された番組
> a program (which was) delivered/streamed this year

> ことし配信された**ネットフリックスの**番組
> a Netflix's program which was delivered this year
> a program delivered this year by Netflix

> ことし配信された**動画配信大手**ネットフリックスの番組
> a program delivered this year by Netflix, a large movie distributing company